# Matlab: Put an image ON TOP of a plot, after the data has been plotted

Tags: matlab

I have searched the internet for a solution to the question above but have had no luck up to now.  I have been producing a number of 2D plots where the origin of (0,0 point) is represented by an image.  I have made these by plotting the data on an image, where the image is all white apart from the desired symbol at the center point (so I can reshape it as needed).  I then move the axis so they cross at the center point.  This all works fine, but I now have to create a number of plots using ‘fill’ to place two shaded areas on the plot that overlap in the center.  This causes the symbol to be difficult to see even using ‘alpha’.

I therefore have two options to get the desired effect, both requiring me to put an image on top of the figure after the data is plotted.  These options are:

1)  I place the image on top of the plot and apply alpha to it (May not look very good as it will mute the plot).

2)  The better option would be to crop the image around the symbol and then position it on top of the plot so the image center is at the origin (I have no idea how to position the image this way).

Both methods need the image to be placed on top of the plot after the data is plotted.  I have tried 'hold on' and calling 'figure(imagesc(Image))' neither work.  I have  Matlab 2012b but no toolboxes (so cannot use subimage etc.)

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 1):

You can set the transparency of individual pixels of an image using the `'AlphaData'` option. So, you can plot the overlay as follows:

```
% plot your data normally
...
hold on
% assuming the overlay is a 11x11 image
image(-5:5,-5:5,image_matrix,'AlphaData',alpha_matrix);
```

`image_matrix` would obviously be the matrix with your image data stored in it, while `alpha_matrix` would be a matrix of the same size as `image_matrix`. Every pixel you want to show would have a value of 1, every pixel you want to hide (the white pixels) would be 0.